# Angular 1 Ui-router - transition to next child sibling

Tags: javascript, angularjs, routes, angular-ui-router, state

I can't quite work out from the documentation on ui-router about how to transition between sibling states effectively using $state.go()

Consider a child state whose url is integer based:
/parent/1, parent/2, parent/3 etc

I need to navigate between child states with a back and next button.

**Workings (routes.js):**

```
// child states: /parent/1, /parent/2, /parent/3 etc
    {
      name: '3-INT-TOTM.detail',
      url: '/:slide_id',
      templateUrl: 'app/html-partials/part-1/3-int.detail.html',
      params: {
        score: null
      },
      controller: function ($scope, $stateParams, $log, $location, $state) {
        // sorts active slide from parent controller slides based on $stateParams
        $scope.slide = $scope.slides[$stateParams.slide_id];

        // Navigation
        $scope.nextSlide = function () {
          $state.go(''); // <-- what goes in here to go forward a child
          // i.e if I'm here: /parent/2 and I want to go to /parent/3?
```

Perhaps something like:

```
$state.go('3-INT-TOTM.detail'[$stateParams.slide_id] +1 );
```

^ definitely wrong, but you can see where I'm going.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Posting the answer myself after some serious digging on the interwebs:

```
{
      name: '3-INT-TOTM.detail',
      url: '/:page',
      templateUrl: 'app/html-partials/part-1/3-int.detail.html',
      params: {
        score: null,
        page: {
          value: '0',
          squash: true
        }
      },
      controller: function ($scope, $stateParams, $log, $location, $state) {

        $scope.page = parseInt($stateParams.page, 10);
        $scope.slide = $scope.slides[$stateParams.page];

        // Navigation
        $scope.prevSlide = function () {
          $state.go('.', {page: $scope.page - 1});
        };
        $scope.nextSlide = function () {
          $state.go('.', {page: $scope.page + 1});
        };
```

Taken from a fantastic article about such routing $state stuff -->
http://www.codelord.net/2015/06/20/simple-pagination-and-url-params-with-ui-router/